# How to Deserialize a list of custom objects

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, asp.net-3.5

I've really hit a roadblock trying to deserialize a list of custom objects over a WCF service. It's using .NET 4. How do I get around the different namespaces. My ASP.NET app is running on 3.5 and the reference sets up ok. Could that be the issue? How do I get around it?

My service is set up like this:

**Contract**

```
namespace MyDomain.Services.Report
{
   [ServiceContract(Name = "ICompanyReport")]
   public interface ICompanyReport
   {
       [OperationContract]
       byte[] GetFooReport(string fooName);
   }

   [Serializable]
   [DataContract(Name="FooReportRecord", Namespace="MyDomain.com"]
   public class FooReportRecord
   {
      [DataMember]
      public int ID {get; set;}
      [DataMember]
      public string Name {get; set;}
   }

}
```

**svc.cs**

```
public class CompanyReport: ICompanyReport
{
    public byte[] GetFooReport(string fooName)
    {
        var data = new List<FooReportRecord>();

        // get data based on fooName and populate data

        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        var bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        bf.Serialize(ms, data);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

**client side:**

```
var ls = proxy.GetFooReport("bar");
var bf = new BinaryFormatter();
var ms = new MemoryStream(ls);

// Unable to find assembly MyDomain.Services.Report error is thrown
var reportData = (List<FooReportRecord>)bf.Deserialize(ms);
```

Comment: why are you returning byte[] and not FooReportRecord?

Comment: When you say "My ASP.NET app is running on 3.5" is your WCF service hosted in an ASP.NET website? or the ASP.NET app is the client?  I'm guessing you mean client here

Comment: The byte[] was an attempt to squish down as much as possible the list of objects. When I was testing, I could get more results using the byte array vs the actual list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your client is your .NET 3.5 app and FooReportRecord is in your .NET 4 wcf library, you will get a compile time error.

Move FooReportRecord to a 3rd class library compiled in .NET 3.5 and reference this from both your WCF app and Client (ASP.NET)

But as @Phil mentioned, why not return FooReportRecord[] instead of byte[]

**Service**

```
public FooReportRecord[] GetFooReport(string fooName)
{
    var data = new List<FooReportRecord>();

    // get data based on fooName and populate data

    return data.ToArray();
}
```

**Client**

```
var proxy = new ServiceReference1.CompanyReportClient();
FooReportRecord[] ls = proxy.GetFooReport("bar");
```

Comment: After looking at this all day I ended up ditching my whole reason for bumping up my reporting service to 4.0. The size of my lists being returned was just too big to try some hacky cross-version deserialization. It wasn't until I saw the "why byte[]" that it caused me to ask myself the same question. Thanks for the help!